# How to compile project, that uses gtest with gcc compiler?

Tags: gcc, g++, googletest

I have simple source code, that includes gtest and launches testing. Here are the file tests.c:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(" init GTest ");
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I launched build using compiler gcc:

```
    gcc -o MY_UNIT_TESTS tests.c -I/usr/include /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a -lpthread
```

And it is failed with this error:

```
In file included from tests.c:1:0:
/usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:54:18: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

If I use compiler g++, everything is ok. I need to test library, that was built using gcc compiler, so my test should be also build with gcc.

How can I build this code using gcc compiler ?

Answer (score -1):

Google Test is written in C++ (and your are tests too) and you need to use g++ to compile your tests. You can build your library with gcc and you can call your C code from your C++ tests, but there are [some things](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) to be aware of.